# Український відповідник російського слова "вялотекущий"?

Tags: переклад, from-russian

Гугл та Мета перекладачі пропонують варіант "млявий", але так як він інколи може не підійти для перекладу (наприклад, коли у нас словосполучення "вялотекущая болезнь"), то чи є ще якийсь відповідник данного слова в нашій мові?

Comment: Не знаю, як там Мета, але Ґуґль шче рає _млявоплинна_, чим це слово не підходить? Ось _млявоплинна хвороба_ цїлком [сі шукає](//www.google.com.ua/search?q=млявоплинна+хвороба&lr=-lang_ru&safe=off).

Comment: [Наказ МОЗ України N 555 від 27 червня 2013 року](http://mtd.dec.gov.ua/images/dodatki/2013_555_HOZL/2013_555_hozl_kn.pdf): "Хлоридно-натрієві ванни показані
пацієнтам з ХОЗЛ з проявами **млявоплинного** запалення і в фазі ремісії процесу". ХОЗЛ тут це "хронічне обструктивне захворювання легені".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Російсько-український народний сучасний словник](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on) містить такий переклад:

> **Вялотекущий** – *млявий, повільний, млявоплинний*.

[Російсько-український словник у 4 томах](http://chtyvo.org.ua/authors/Hnatiuk_Iryna/Rosiisko-ukrainskyi_slovnyk_u_4_tomakh_Tom_1_AY/) (Т.1, с. 429) теж подає, що:

> **Вялотекущий** - *млявоплинний*.

Однак у [Миттєвому російсько-українському онлайн перекладачу](http://www.m-translate.com.ua/perekladach/russian/ru-uk#text==%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9%0A&direction=ru-uk) зафіксований ще такий варіант:

> **Вялотекущий** - *уповільнений*.

Мені ж більше подобається варіан №3 "уповільнений", однак "млявоплинний" теж можна використовувати.

Comment: Уповільнений - це "замедленный". Млявоплинний більше підходить для "вялотекущий".